# Using ggplot, How does combine lines and polygons based on dates?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, polygon, geom-bar

Let's say that I have the following data frames:

```
Date_spill<-rev(seq(as.Date("2019-02-28"), length = 3135, by = "-1 day"))
Total<-data.frame(Total_H7=runif(3135, min=0.6, max = 0.8))
Total_var<-data.frame(Total_H7=runif(3135, min=0.4, max = 0.55))
CPM_period<-data.frame(x=c(as.numeric(Date_spill[702]), as.numeric(Date_spill[1402]), as.numeric(Date_spill[702]), as.numeric(Date_spill[1402]), as.numeric(Date_spill[1970]), as.numeric(Date_spill[2145]), as.numeric(Date_spill[1970]), as.numeric(Date_spill[2145])
), 
y=c(min(Total_var$Total_H7), min(Total_var$Total_H7), max(Total$Total_H7), max(Total$Total_H7), min(Total_var$Total_H7), min(Total_var$Total_H7), max(Total$Total_H7), max(Total$Total_H7)),
 period=c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"))
```

I want to plot a graph that combines two lines and two polygons. I am using the following code:

```
Total_ReVarCov<-ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(y = Total$Total_H7, x=Date_spill), color="skyblue3", linetype="twodash", alpha=0.6)+ #First time series
  geom_line(aes(y = Total_var$Total_H7, x=Date_spill), color="darkred", linetype="twodash", alpha=0.6)+ #Second time series
geom_polygon(aes(x=CPM_period$x, y=CPM_period$y, group=CPM_period$period))+ #Two polygons
 geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(Date_spill[2528]), linetype=4)+ #An specific fact
  labs(x = "", y="Aggregated Index", colour="Variables")
```

which gives me the following error `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only` I am sure that the code is related to `geom_polygon` because the error appears when I write the line that would have to plot the polygons. Using my original data the plot without polygons is the following:

[image]

How can I plot polygons using dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you converted your date variable to a numeric when defining your dataset `CPM_period` and also in the `geom_vline`. Therefore keep it as a date:

```r
library(ggplot2)

Date_spill<-rev(seq(as.Date("2019-02-28"), length = 3135, by = "-1 day"))
Total<-data.frame(Total_H7=runif(3135, min=0.6, max = 0.8))
Total_var<-data.frame(Total_H7=runif(3135, min=0.4, max = 0.55))
CPM_period<-data.frame(x= Date_spill[c(702, 1402, 702, 1402, 1970, 2145, 1970,2145)], 
y=c(min(Total_var$Total_H7), min(Total_var$Total_H7), max(Total$Total_H7), max(Total$Total_H7), min(Total_var$Total_H7), min(Total_var$Total_H7), max(Total$Total_H7), max(Total$Total_H7)),
period=c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(y = Total$Total_H7, x=Date_spill), color="skyblue3", linetype="twodash", alpha=0.6)+ #First time series
  geom_line(aes(y = Total_var$Total_H7, x=Date_spill), color="darkred", linetype="twodash", alpha=0.6)+ #Second time series
  geom_polygon(aes(x=CPM_period$x, y=CPM_period$y, group=CPM_period$period))+ #Two polygons
  geom_vline(xintercept=Date_spill[2528], linetype=4)+ #An specific fact
  labs(x = "", y="Aggregated Index", colour="Variables")
```

[image]